# google sign in permission

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-signin

Why did react-native-google-signin require extra permissons like read, send, delete, and manage users email?
It should only asks to read user's email.

can we change this?

here is my signin configuaration:

```
async _setupGoogleSignin() {
    try {
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true });
        await GoogleSignin.configure({
            webClientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            offlineAccess: true,
            scopes: [

                'https://mail.google.com/'
            ]
        });
    } catch (err) {}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After adding scope : `[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly]` issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the scope part from configuration, it will fix it.